# How to insert a series of elements in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

How to insert a series of elements in an array

The current code to insert one element in an array is as follows:

```
public static void getArrayElement()
{

    try
    {
        if(initialSize==1)
        {
            //Get the user input
            System.out.print("Enter the element: ");
            getElement = key.nextInt();

            //Assign the user input to the array
            for(int i=0; i<index; i++)
            {
                array[i] = getElement;
            }

        }

        //If the size of the array is not 1 use this
        else
        {
            //Gets the user input
            System.out.print("Enter the element: ");
            getElement = key.nextInt();

            //Create a new empty array with a new size
            int[] temp = new int[index];

            //Assign the old array into the new array
            for(int j = 0; j < index-1; j++)
            {
                temp[j] = array[j];
            }

            //Change the size of the old array
            array = new int [index];

            //Assign the temporary array into the new array with its new size
            for(int aSize = 0; aSize< array.length; aSize++)
            {
                array[aSize] = temp[aSize];
                int k = array.length;
                array[k-1] = getElement;
            }

            //Pass the array into sortArray method for sorting
            sortArray(array, index);

         }

            //Increment the index and initialSize
           index++;
           initialSize++;
      }
      catch(InputMismatchException e)
     {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            System.exit(0);
     }

  }
```

As you see the above code can insert only one element at a time. But if I want to insert a bunch of elements at a time, How do i do that ?

Comment: Just for the record: `void getArrayElement()` is quite misleading since `getXXX()` indicates a return value.

Comment: Additional questions : is `key` a `Scanner`? Why don't you use a list instead of an array? That way you'd not have to handle the copying around yourself.

Comment: If you need to maintain the collection sorted, why don't you use PriorityQueue? And if you don't have to, then ArrayList?

Comment: so how can modify to allow enter random number

Comment: is this your code or you're trying to modify someone else's code?

Comment: yes my code >>> but my instructor tell me to make program insert random number

Answer (score 2):

Before finding an answer it is better to understand what arrays are.

> Array is a set a of homogeneous elements stored in a contiguous memory
>   location.

This makes a limitation that Arrays need to know the size when they are initialized to reserve enough space from the memory. This makes insertion not possible at all in the parent array. For that you will have to do an arraycopy or create a new array with a different size.

For example,

```
int[] array = new int[10]; //Initializes an integer array of size 10.
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
     array[i] = i;
}//stores values from 0 to 9.
```

Now if you intend to insert one or 'n' elements at the start, you have to either create a new array with size "size of prev array + 1" or "size of prev array + n" respectively. And perform an array copy followed by an insertion at the start.

So, if you want a dynamic object doing this for you (inserting one, inserting in bulk), you will have to define your custom capacity that the array can hold. And then you will have to increase the capacity based on your preference.

Developing on this problem, you will reinvent the Java's [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). So better use it in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If `key` is a `Scanner` you could just do this:

```
while( key.hasNextInt() ) {
  int i = key.nextInt();
  //do with i whatever you want
}
```

I'd also suggest using a list instead of an array. Then just pass the list to `Collections.sort(list)` to keep it sorted.

Although lists only allow you to add objects you could make use of autoboxing and convert an `int` to `Integer` upon inserting.

Alternatively there are libraries that support primitive lists out there - Google Guava and Apache Commons, for example, should provide some.

Another alternative might be sorted collections like Apache Common's `TreeBag` which allows you to add multiple duplicate items into a sorted structure.

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy content of temp into array. You can achieve this in one at most two steps

`if (temp.length > array.length)
 array = new int[temp.length];
System.arraycopy(temp, 0, array, 0, temp.length) ;`

Comment: more info about the method in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)